# Heuristics to choose most appropriate chart for given data

Tags: gui-design, charts

I have typical web app. where the user effectively makes a query and he/she gets back some data. The data is in the format of 1 dimension/1 metric.
For instance:

- city/population
- country/population
- gender/population

on returning the data my javascript uses the google charts api and displays either a pie chart or table chart or a line chart...

Depending...

What I discovered is that if I have two or three cities a pie chart is perfect, however if I have hundreds of cities a Pie chart is awful. (and hence I switch to a table chart)

My question is:

What's the algorithm to choose the most appropriate chart depending on the data ?
Have people made some studies on this ?

For instance one simple answer (e.g. my current implementation) says:

> **if** the number of cities is smaller than 5 use a pie chart
>   **else** use a table chart

Can somebody suggest a better algorithm ?

Also can somebody point me to some external resources where this problem is discussed?

Comment: What pie charts are best at is showing proportions, e.g. % votes for each candidate, breakdown of a group by age range, etc. It sounds like you're showing independent values. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Workshop result](http://libraryassessment.org/bm~doc/workshop_lyons_ray.pdf), you should not have more than five "parts" in a pie chart, just as you also suggested. (Pie charts are covered about 3/4 into the article).

The workshop also discusses a range of other best practices when displaying data graphically.

Comment: Quite a lot of stuff in your link. Thanks for that. Interesting thanks

Comment: I thought that too! 208 pages of goodness! =)